# How to use HttpURLConnection to send request without handling response in Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have this code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

What I want is just to send a request to `url`.

I don't care about response.

I just need to send request.

How I do that?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash so after I set method as `POST` it automatically send request?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you. What I had should do is to add `connection.getResponseCode();` to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You try can with `post` method instead of `get` method

Comment: So after I set method as `POST` it automatically send request?

Comment: Basically, **GET is used to request data from a specified resource.**  and **POST is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.**

Comment: You need to send the data using 
  `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  // Send post request
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  
  //Send send the parameter to the server
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
  wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
  wr.flush();
  wr.close();`

Comment: I don't need to send data. I just need to send a request. Like: `mydom.com/accepted`

Comment: then just `connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // Send post request connection.setDoOutput(true);` is enough to send request